# Close ASP.NET page

Tags: javascript, asp.net

The following button does not close a Chrome page/tab on click.  What am I missing?

```
<asp:Button id="Test" runat="server" Text="Close Page" onClientClick="window.close(); return true;"
```

Comment: Did you read the documentation [Window.close()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close)? → "*Scripts may not close windows that were not opened by script*"

Comment: @Igor   Thank you for the link to the documentation.  
I wonder how else I can close the window.

Comment: With the exception of the asking the user to close the browser tab you can't.